# Coercion Failed: Unable to transform the input lookup data into the requested type

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I need your help in solving this below Issue:

I have a list called "Project Lead Engineers" it has Lead Eng. and copied "Additional Engineers" and both of the columns are of type People picker and the table is in this format:

Title ----- Approvers ------ CopiedEmps

1  ---------- Emp1 ---------- Emp2; Emp3

2  ---------- Emp4 ---------- Emp5; Emp6

and to pick the desired line and store the result in a variable of type string, I do the following:

[image]

anyway I send an e-mail using the variables created to the approvers and CC-ed the notified Emps:

[image]

but everytime the WF reaches this step I get the Error mentioned in the Title...
it's something to do with the To and CC fields but I don't know how to solve it.

so if you have any idea how to solve it, you will make my day.
thanks in advance.